# php looping through tab separated file

Tags: php, arrays, fopen

this code works great. The only thing i can figure out how to do is convert this to an array. I have 26 to 38 rows (that number varies) what i would like to do is have it turn each row of results into its own array.

```
 $row[1] col1, col3, col4, col5, col8
 $row[2] col1, col3, col4, col5, col8
 $row[3] col1, col3, col4, col5, col8
```

I then want to be able to access each result like this: echo $row[1]; How can i do this and how do i know when the row ends?

```
<?php     
$a = file_get_contents( "t_rac.txt" ); 
$a = str_replace( array( "\r\n" , "\t" ) , array( "[NEW*LINE]" , "[tAbul*Ator]" ) , $a ); 
foreach( explode( "[NEW*LINE]" , $a ) AS $lines ) {  
    foreach( explode( "[tAbul*Ator]" , $lines ) AS $li ) { 
    if (strpos($li,',') !== false) 
    {
    }
    else {
    echo $li; 
    }
    echo "<br>";
    }  
} 
?>
```

Comment: you already have the `foreach`, and exploded the strings, you could just reassign them into another one if you like

Comment: How can i determine when the end of the row happens?

Comment: just check the count of the first explosion, that should give you have many rows you have, that number will determine whether you are on the end. or just process after outside the foreach, that should be the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
 //use file to get array of lines
 $arrayContent=file("t_rac.txt");
 $returnArray=array();
 $i=0;

 foreach($arrayContent as $row){
   $returnArray[$i++]=explode(",\t", $row);
 }

 ?>
```

As a result you have multi-dimensional array. You can use it like:

```
echo $returnArray[0][3]; //prints single col5 value
echo implode(",\t", $returnArray[0]); //prints col1, col3, col4, col5, col8
```

**EDIT**
Make sure you have tabs between cols.

t_rac.txt content:

```
 $row[1]    col1,   col3,   col4,   col5,   col8
 $row[2]    col1,   col3,   col4,   col5,   col8
 $row[3]    col1,   col3,   col4,   col5,   col8
```

Comment: This is exactly what im looking for... but im getting this error **Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /home1/donavons/public_html/php/index.php on line 17** Here is line 17 and 18 `echo $returnArray[0][3]; 
echo implode(",\t", $returnArray[0]);`

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the array name but also make sure that there are tabs between the cols.

Comment: Thank you @Grzegorz Krauze trying it out now

Answer (score 0):

this will build a php array with the numbers 1 through 10:

```
$a = array();
for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) {
    $a[] = $i;
}
```

the `[]` notation automatically appends to the end of the array, no need for a subscript

note that php `explode` returns an array, so you already have the array of cols.  To omit the row[] from the beginning, use `array_shift($a)` on the array

Comment: Thank you @Andras I forgot that explode did that!